# Stable current source with discrete components

Tags: mosfet, diodes, bjt, temperature, current-source

The purpose of this is to *compare and learn* different circuit *topologies*, not use of the shelf solutions which obviously provide cheaper, simpler and better results. Considering this requirement (no use of ICs, not even a matched pair), the parameter ranges given below and that the load should be connected to the voltage source:

Can we get better temperature stability *and* input voltage regulation by an order of magnitude (e.g. < 100uA)? To focus on the main goal, let's disregard the temperature coefficient of the metal film resistors.

The load regulation of the circuit on the left is already good enough. I've used different BJTs on the right do avoid depending on any form of matching between the discrete components.

The parameters are: 10 <= Vin <= 30, 0 <= Temp. (C) <= 50, 0 <= RL <= 1200, Isource ~ 5mA

Manually adjusting the central value with a trimpot is fine, let's not add this concern either.

Note: the ranges below are simulated by fixing all but one parameter.

[image]

Comment: Please be clearer about your question - at the moment *"Can we get better temperature stability and input voltage regulation by an order of magnitude (e.g. < 100uA)?"* doesn't really mean much. Also, what does this mean: *"Manually adjusting the central value with a trimpot is fine"*?

Comment: @Andyaka by voltage regulation I mean: if the input varies from 10 to 30, other parameters fixed, is there a topology that provides less than 100uA variation at the source? By temperature stability I mean: if the temperature varies from 0 to 50C, with the other parameters fixed,  is there a topology that provides less than 100uA variation at the source?

Comment: Regarding your second question: I don't want to make things more complicated by adding a restriction on the exactness of the central value. Different topologies for better voltage regulation and temperature stability are the main goal.

Comment: Yes, I think you can improve the performance by using more complex circuits. For example: separate voltage reference (bandgap like circuit), then use an opamp like circuit (gm stage) to copy that reference voltage across a resistor. Then the circuit would be somewhat similar to what would be on an IC. To avoid having to use matched transistor pairs we can use emitter resistors to match non-matched transistors better.

Comment: Sure @Bimpelrekkie, I agree with you. Implementing a circuit which is as complex as a complete Op. Amp. with discrete components is more than what changed from one circuit to the other above. But I understand that what you propose is not going that far. I will search according to your suggestions.

Comment: Realize that a suitable "opamp" (actually gm cell) can be made with as few as 4 to 6 transistors and some resistors. There's no need to make a "proper" opamp with multiple stages. see: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/experiments/chpt-5/simple-op-amp/

Comment: @vangelo Ask a specific question, this is a Q&A site

Comment: One topology has 3 components: transistor with grounded emitter, resistor1 from VDD to collector, resistor from collector to base.

Comment: You want a discrete design for a \$5\:\text{mA}\$ current source/sink that holds to within \$\pm 2\%\$ over a supply voltage range from \$10\:\text{V}\$ to \$30\:\text{V}\$ and a temperature range from \$0^\circ\:\text{C}\$ to \$50^\circ\:\text{C}\$ and any self-heating differences related to a load that varies from a dead short to \$1.2\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and handles transistor vagaries, etc? Sounds like it needs some thinking (and research -- particularly the work done in the 1960's, I believe.)

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but you may want to take a look at the tempco of an IR-LED or a 5.6V zener they are convenient for such circuits